# Cursor Adapter with Date-Sorted Section Headers

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursor

I basically made a listview with Alphabet-Indexed section headers by following [this](http://eshyu.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/cursoradapter-with-alphabet-indexed-section-headers/) tutorial. I'm trying to make the same, sorted with dates.

This is how my date column in database is fed with.
`String currentDateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());`

**Can some one help me with pointers or snippets on sort by date.?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know is using `java.util.Date`. It's almost nothing more than a wrapper around a long value corresponding to difference between the time it represents, and the epoch, `Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT`. So you can store in the DB longs (instead of strings), and then when querying the table sort the results by the "date" (longs), constructing dates out of those values. All this because sqlite doesn't support date formats.

somethign like this:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from table sort by table_column_date");
for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
     Date date = new Date(c.getLong("table_column_date"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is using the [adapter-ki](https://github.com/mobsandgeeks/adapter-kit)t library

First, implement a DateSectionizer. It loads the date timestamp from your model and "rounds" it to the beginning of this day, consequently timestamps of the same day will have the same formatted day string.

```
public class DateSectionizer implements Sectionizer<Cursor>
{
   private static final SimpleDateFormat YMD_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMMMM-dd");

   private static long beginning_of_day(long timestamp)
   {
      Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
      c.setTimeInMillis( timestamp  );
      c.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0 );
      c.set( Calendar.MINUTE, 0 );
      c.set( Calendar.SECOND, 0 );
      c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0 );
      return c.getTimeInMillis();
   }

   @Override
   public String getSectionTitleForItem( Cursor cursor )
   {
      return YMD_FORMAT.format(new Date(beginning_of_day(cursor.getLong( 2 ));
   }
}
```

Secondly, wrap a SimpleSectionAdapter around your already existing CursorAdapter:

```
 Context c = getApplicationContext();

 YourCursorAdapter yca = new YourCursorAdaper(c , your_cursor, true);
 your_list_view.setAdapter( new SimpleSectionAdapter<Cursor>(c,yca, R.layout.header_layout, R.id.date , new DateSectionizer() ));
```